# Using 'as' like with an *ngIf

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

When using an `*ngIf`, you can do something like `*ngIf = (value$ | async).property as prop`  and then use `prop` throughout your code without needing to repeat the long `(value$ | async).property`  each time. However, this only works if `(value$ | async).property` is a truthy value - and not if it is zero for instance.

My question is - how can I still reap the benefits of `as` but still have the element show if the value is falsy? Or better yet, is there a way to use `as` outside of an `*ngIf` or the like?

Comment: You can define a property in your `component.ts` that you could use in your code. That seems to me the best way of doing so. It's not really intended (and I don't think it's possible) to define prop outside of the `*ngIf` scope. However, what's the point of using `prop` outside of the `*ngIf` scope if you know it has no value? You can always define a `*ngIf="(value | async) as prop; else noProp"` and assign `#noProp` to a `ng-template` element somewhere in your component's template.

Comment: Thanks, but if I define it in my component then I need to subscribe to the observable, as opposed to taking advantage of the async pipe. And I want to show the falsey value since in this case it is an enum. I still want to show the first value, I just want a way to shortcut the access to the property. If there is no solution, I'll just repeat the (value$ | async).property in all the places I need it within the element

Answer (score 2):

PMO1948, "the trick" is create an object, credits to [Yury Katkov](https://medium.com/@yurykatkov/how-to-avoid-multiple-async-pipes-in-angular-ff0d51a8d368)

```html
<div *ngIf="{values: (value$ | async)} as prop">
    ..inside use, e.g.
    {{prop.values?.property}}
    <div *ngIf="!prop.values">
        the observable return nothing
    </div>
</div>
```

If `"value$ |async"` return nothing, the `*ngIf` exist anyway

[Sample Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-obr6ko?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: If I did that, I would still need to use `prop.values.property` as opposed to the direct `prop` I can use otherwise. So really I have just changed it from `(value$ | async).property` to `prop.values.property` which does not really shorten it at all

Comment: There is also a syntax error in your code - there is a closing `}` with no opening one

Comment: thanks @OwenKelvin to correct and thanks PMO1948 to the comment

Answer (score 0):

Below is another trick you can implement using `||`

```html
<div *ngIf="(value$ | async) || {}  as prop">
    ..inside use, e.g.
    {{prop.property}}
    <div *ngIf="!prop.property">
        the observable return nothing
    </div>
</div>
```

[See Demo Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-awkz6n?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

**Update**

Came across [ngrxLet Structural Directive](https://ngrx.io/guide/component/let#ngrxlet-structural-directive) and this looks like an interesting solution

> The ***ngrxLet** directive serves a convenient way of binding observables to a view context (a dom element scope)
> The ***ngrxLet** directive is provided through the ReactiveComponentModule.`

```typescript
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ReactiveComponentModule } from '@ngrx/component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    // other imports
    ReactiveComponentModule
  ]
})
export class MyFeatureModule {}
```

With the above you can use it

```html
<div  *ngrxLet="value$ as prop">
    ..inside use, e.g.
    {{prop.property}}
    <div *ngIf="!prop.property">
        the observable return nothing
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: While that does still enable the display, for the first object of the enum I do not get the proper value, rather I get `{}`

Comment: @PMO1948 this may be a late update but I believe its worth checking out